# Tracking a tweeter hashtag (keyword) with stream API

Tags: node.js, tweetstream

I am trying to track all tweets by given hashtag or keyword. The problem is I can stream the tweets when I use a simple keyword like 'animal' but when I change it to say 'animal4666' then it doesn't work. No reply is received. I am using the code below.

```
    twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'animal4666' }, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(util.inspect(data));
        });
    });
```

I have made two tweets from different account like following:

'#animal4666 a'

'#animal4666 trying to find out what is going on?'

Above tweets are successfully retrieved using search API but because of the rate limitations on search API I need to use stream API so that i can check for new tweets every two seconds with node.js

The addon I am using of node.js: https://github.com/jdub/node-twitter

Can someone please help?

Comment: Why vote down?, explanation would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you look the [code](https://github.com/jdub/node-twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter.js) of the library you are using, it seems that there is nothing potentially wrong
it only has a workaround when you pass an array in the track param, but is not the case

```
// Workaround for node-oauth vs. twitter commas-in-params bug
if ( params && params.track && Array.isArray(params.track) ) {
    params.track = params.track.join(',')
 }
```

So looking in to the [official api docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track) for track method, I see two caveats that may are relevant.

> Each phrase must be between 1 and 60 bytes, inclusive.

I think yours are shorter but is something to take in mind

And what I think is your real problem:

> Exact matching of phrases (equivalent to quoted phrases in most search
> engines) is not supported.
>
> Punctuation and special characters will be considered part of the term
> they are adjacent to. In this sense, "hello." is a different track
> term than "hello". However, matches will ignore punctuation present in
> the Tweet. So "hello" will match both "hello world" and "my brother
> says hello." Note that punctuation is not considered to be part of a
> #hashtag or @mention, so a track term containing punctuation will not match either #hashtags or @mentions.

You can check online your tweet text to see if it match [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/keyword-matching)